# Tensorflow LSTM model not predicting results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I've built a LSTM model in tensorflow, but it's not predicting any useful results.
My data is essentially a sequence of codes for multiple IDs, and I want my model to predict the next code in the sequence for each ID (classification).

I've structured my model so that it takes in 5 sequences of  `(ID, dx1, dx2, dx3)`, all of which have the same `ID`, then want it to output the next `dx1, dx2, dx3` in the sequence.

```
num_cats = 4 # number of categorical features
n_steps = 5 # number of timesteps in each sample
cat_size = [df['enrolid'].nunique(),  df['dx1'].nunique(), df['dx2'].nunique(), df['dx3'].nunique()] # number of categories in each categorical feature
cat_embd_dim = [1191095, 100, 50, 20] # embedding dimension for each categorical feature



input_enrolid = Input(shape=(n_steps,), name='input_enrolid')    
input_dx1 = Input(shape=(n_steps,), name='input_dx1')
input_dx2 = Input(shape=(n_steps,), name='input_dx2')
input_dx3 = Input(shape=(n_steps,), name='input_dx3')

embed_dx1 =  Embedding(df['dx1'].nunique(), cat_embd_dim[1])(input_dx1)
embed_dx2 =  Embedding(df['dx2'].nunique(), cat_embd_dim[2])(input_dx2)
embed_dx3 =  Embedding(df['dx3'].nunique(), cat_embd_dim[3])(input_dx3)

lstm_dx1 = LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_steps, num_cats))(embed_dx1)
lstm_dx2 = LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_steps, num_cats))(embed_dx2)
lstm_dx3 = LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_steps, num_cats))(embed_dx3)

output_dx1 = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(lstm_dx1)
output_dx2 = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(lstm_dx2)
output_dx3 = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(lstm_dx3)

model = Model( [input_enrolid, input_dx1, input_dx2, input_dx3], [output_dx1, output_dx2, output_dx3])
```

My `model.summary()` is as follows:

```
Model: "functional_15"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_dx1 (InputLayer)          [(None, 5)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_dx2 (InputLayer)          [(None, 5)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_dx3 (InputLayer)          [(None, 5)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_39 (Embedding)        (None, 5, 100)       154500      input_dx1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_40 (Embedding)        (None, 5, 50)        79750       input_dx2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_41 (Embedding)        (None, 5, 20)        28600       input_dx3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_51 (LSTM)                  (None, 32)           17024       embedding_39[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_52 (LSTM)                  (None, 32)           10624       embedding_40[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_53 (LSTM)                  (None, 32)           6784        embedding_41[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_enrolid (InputLayer)      [(None, 5)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)                (None, 1)            33          lstm_51[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)                (None, 1)            33          lstm_52[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)                (None, 1)            33          lstm_53[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 297,381
Trainable params: 297,381
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then, I compile and fit my model:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics='accuracy' )
model.fit([ X_tr_cat1, X_tr_cat2, X_tr_cat3, X_tr_cat4], [y_train_dx1, y_train_dx2, y_train_dx3], epochs=3, batch_size = 1000)
```

However, upon fitting my model, I see some accuracies and losses that don't look too reassuring:

```
Epoch 1/3
1192/1192 [==============================] - 37s 31ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_21_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_22_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_23_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_21_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - dense_22_accuracy: 8.3956e-07 - dense_23_accuracy: 8.3956e-07
Epoch 2/3
1192/1192 [==============================] - 37s 31ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_21_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_22_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_23_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_21_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - dense_22_accuracy: 8.3956e-07 - dense_23_accuracy: 8.3956e-07
Epoch 3/3
1192/1192 [==============================] - 37s 31ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_21_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_22_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_23_loss: 0.0000e+00 - dense_21_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - dense_22_accuracy: 8.3956e-07 - dense_23_accuracy: 8.3956e-07
```

Not only is there 0 loss on the three outputs and 0 accuracy for the first dense layer, but none of the values change in each epoch!

Furthermore, when I try to get the model to predict on the data I used to train it, I get:

```
> y_prob=model.predict([ X_tr_cat1, X_tr_cat2, X_tr_cat3, X_tr_cat4])

> [array([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        ...,
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]], dtype=float32),
 array([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        ...,
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]], dtype=float32),
 array([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        ...,
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Upon trying to see the actual predictions for `dx1`:

```
> y_prob[0].argmax(axis=-1)
> array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Looks like it's predicting the same `0` dx1 prediction for every sequence, where the empty string `''` has been encoded as 0 in my data.

For additional clarification, my input `X_tr_cat1` looks like

```
> X_tr_cat1
> array([[     0,      0,      0,      0,      0],
       [     0,      0,      0,      0,      0],
       [     0,      0,      0,      0,      0],
       ...,
       [238218, 238218, 238218, 238218, 238218],
       [238218, 238218, 238218, 238218, 238218],
       [238218, 238218, 238218, 238218, 238218]])
```

and has shape `(1191095, 5).`

While `cat2, cat3, cat4` may contain different values, the shape and structure are the same - they just refer to the codes, while `cat1` refers to the `id` : the first `[0,0, 0, 0, 0]` means that the id was 0 for ID 0 at times 1,2,3,4,5.

My `y_train_dx1` output looks like

```
array([[ 877],
       [1313],
       [1313],
       ...,
       [   0],
       [   0],
       [   0]])
```

and has shape `(1191095, 1)` - just the next `dx1` code in the sequence for each input sequence.
I really don't know what is wrong with my model here - I think my input arrays are formatted correctly? But I'm not sure as I'm a bit new to TF.

Any suggestions on what to fix?

Comment: `Dense(1, activation='softmax')` you have 1 unit so your predictions in shape of `(1,)`. Softmax outputs will sum up to one(1), with 1 unit you are just outputting a vector of ones(1s) everytime. Also argmax with with a shape (1,) does not make sense.

Comment: @Frightera I guess I'm just trying to find the most likely prediction for each of the `dx1,dx2,dx3` outputs, along with their probabilities. Should I use a different activation function, then? I see that `sigmoid` is another classification activation function, but it's equivalent to a 2-element softmax, so that doesn't sound right either?

Comment: If I were to try using `Dense(num_categories, activation = 'softmax')` to get the probabilities  of each category in the last layer, would I have to reformat my `y_train_dx1` data? As is, I get a Shapes are incompatible error.